# How much footage can Black Ops' theatre mode store?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Is there a limit to how much data Theatre Mode can store (for example, X number of minutes or X matches), or is it just limited by the amount of memory left in your console (or computer's) hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Gamespot, the clips save to [callofduty.com](http://www.callofduty.com/):

> You can only save six clips. These are
>   the six you can keep in your
>   fileshare. You cannot download any to
>   your HDD. You can't get the clips
>   rendered to your computer, you can
>   save screenshots to your computer from
>   callofduty.com/blackops. Go to the
>   theater tab on the site and you can
>   select and save your screenshots.